# IN statement in WHERE clause not functioning as expected

Tags: mysql

Below is my database structure:

[image]

> Now I want to perform search on this table called 'posts'.
>
> Say I want look for PostUUID(field) where the details are as below:

**-subid =1,2

-postcode=56000

-pricing-100**

> In the above database image, there are 3 users meeting these criteria,
>   namely vani,kalni and nair.
>
> So the result should return 6 rows with unique PostUUID.

My query:

```
$a=$data['sub'];
foreach($a as $v=>$k) 
  {

    $key[]=$v;

  }
//variables
 $key2=implode(',',$key);
$postcode=$data['postcode'];
$rate=$data['rate'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts,subjects WHERE posts.subid IN (:key2) AND posts.pricing=:rate2  AND posts.Poscode=:postcode2 AND subjects.subid=posts.subid ORDER BY posts.Poscode DESC LIMIT 60");

    $statement->execute(array(':key2' => $key2,':rate2'=>$rate,':postcode2'=>$postcode));

$json = array();
 while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
    // array_push($json, array($row['Name'], $row['PostUUID']));
     array_push($json, array("name" => $row['Name'], "id" => $row['PostUUID'],"rate" => $row['pricing'],"postcode" => $row['Poscode'],"subject" => $row['subname'],"reputation" => $row['Reputation'],"plus" => $row['ReviewPlus'],"neg" => $row['ReviewNeg'],"weekM" => $row['week_morning'],"weekA" => $row['week_afternoon'],"weekE" => $row['week_evening'],"endM" => $row['weekend_morning'],"endA" => $row['weekend_afternoon'],"endE" => $row['weekend_evening']));
 }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($json);
```

I `var_dump($json)` and it showed only one set of data for the `$key array`. It din't not iterate through the second item in the $key array to fetch its data from the database. Why does IN not returning correctly here?

Comment: What's in `$data['sub']`? You have to figure out why `$key` only contains one value (hence `$key2` containing only one id)

Comment: I did echo $key2, and it did show 2 ids as comma separated. And $data['sub'] contains array of value for sub id.